# How does tell() in python file handling work

Tags: python-3.x, file, file-handling

```
f = open("test.txt","w")
s= "This\nThis\nThis"
f.write(s)
f.close()

f= open("test.txt","r")
w=''
for i in f:
    for j in i:
        w = w+j
print(w)
print("Number of Characters",len(w))
print("Current Position of handler",f.tell())

f.close()
```

The output of the above is

```
This
This 
This
Number of Characters 14
Current Position of handler 16
```

As per the file, there are 12 characters and 2 escape sequences so the number of characters is 14. I got it. But I did not get why the `tell()` function returns 17

Answer (score 0):

Just an assumption.

I think, in your case, just for '\n', the pointer is moving twice. First, after reading the newline character i.e. \n, the pointer is moving one step right. Secondly, because of newline character, the pointer is going to the beginning of the next line. That's why an extra count is being added to tell() function's result. This won't be happen for other escape characters like '\t' etc.

I ran some examples on my system. You can notice the results one by one.

**Example 1**

```
f = open("test.txt","w")
s= "\t"
f.write(s)
f.close()

f= open("test.txt","r")
w=''
for i in f:
    for j in i:
        w = w+j
print(w)
print("Number of Characters",len(w))
print("Current Position of handler",f.tell())

f.close()
```

Output

```
>>>python .\test.py

Number of Characters 1
Current Position of handler 1
```

**Example 2**

```
f = open("test.txt","w")
s= "\n"
f.write(s)
f.close()

f= open("test.txt","r")
w=''
for i in f:
    for j in i:
        w = w+j
print(w)
print("Number of Characters",len(w))
print("Current Position of handler",f.tell())

f.close()
```

Output

```
>>>python .\test.py

Number of Characters 1
Current Position of handler 2
```

**Example 3**

```
f = open("test.txt","w")
s= "ThisThisThis"
f.write(s)
f.close()

f= open("test.txt","r")
w=''
for i in f:
    for j in i:
        w = w+j
print(w)
print("Number of Characters",len(w))
print("Current Position of handler",f.tell())

f.close()
```

Output

```
>>>python .\test.py
ThisThisThis
Number of Characters 12
Current Position of handler 12
```

**Example 4**

```
f = open("test.txt","w")
s= "ThisThisThis\n"
f.write(s)
f.close()

f= open("test.txt","r")
w=''
for i in f:
    for j in i:
        w = w+j
print(w)
print("Number of Characters",len(w))
print("Current Position of handler",f.tell())

f.close()
```

Output

```
>>>python .\test.py
ThisThisThis

Number of Characters 13
Current Position of handler 14
```

**Example 5**

```
f = open("test.txt","w")
s= "ThisThisThis\t"
f.write(s)
f.close()

f= open("test.txt","r")
w=''
for i in f:
    for j in i:
        w = w+j
print(w)
print("Number of Characters",len(w))
print("Current Position of handler",f.tell())

f.close()
```

Output

```
>>>python .\test.py
ThisThisThis
Number of Characters 13
Current Position of handler 13
```

For your case, you used \n two times in your string. You can count 2 instead of 1 for every \n while guessing the result of tell(). So, 4 + 2 + 4 + 2 + 4 = 16.

Comment: Thank you, Mr Debtanu Gupta. My question is why only in the new line character it has to move twice. Is that mean \n takes 2 bytes in python.

Comment: I think, the file pointer moves after reading one character. For example, if it reads 'A', then after reading, it goes immediate right of the character 'A'. But for '\n', first it goes to the right after reading the character, then it goes to the next line. So you can see that after '\n', two operations are being done. First, going right, second, going to the new line.